# How can I duplicate the vertices of an edge to move it without affecting surrounding edges?

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I need to push an edge in but by doing so the connected edges will also get dragged in. To do this with faces I can just extrude inwards but with an edge it just creates a new edge disconnected from the surrounding faces.

Here is the edge:

[image]

How can I duplicate the vertices on the top and bottom of the edge so I can push it in without moving the edges above or below it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there is a one step solution, but aside from just manually doing everything I think the new *extend edge* tool (<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>) is about the closest to a one-step as anything I can think of:

[image]

Note that the selection is extended towards the initial position of the mouse when <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> is pressed, which can be confusing before you get used to it.

---

That said, I think in your particular situation I would do something more like this:

[image]